# Eliminar valores repetidos array

Tags: php, bucle-for, foreach

quiero eliminar ciertos elementos del siguiente array:

[image: Array original]

Por otro lado, el usuario pasa el nombre de la pagina a eliminar, y mediante una consulta al objeto obtengo el siguiente array:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces hago la siguiente iteracción para obtener los elementos a eliminar en base a un objeto, pero en primer lugar me salen repetidos y no puedo eliminarlos del array resultante.

```
$array =   explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', $noPages));
$array2 = [];
$eliminar=[];
  
foreach ($pages as $site) :
       

        foreach ($site->pages() as $key => $page) :
            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($array); $i++) {

              
                if (strtolower($page->title()) === strtolower($array[$i])) {
                    array_push($eliminar,[$page->url(), $page->title()]);
                } else {

                    array_push($array2, [$page->url(), $page->title()]);
                  

                }
            }

        endforeach;
   
    endforeach;
```

Si aplico ese codigo, me da como resultado que se han eliminado los valores que indicaba el usuario, pero ahora salen repetidos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es restar los valores contenidos en el array $eliminar del array2, ¿Alguna pista? Muchas gracias.

Comment: No lo entiendo Bien.. podrias colocar una Entrada Y salida de ejemplo de como quieres que aparezca

Comment: Si, ayudaría mucho poner un ejemplo de cual es la entrada y cual es la salida que desea

Comment: Lo acabo de editar. Gracias, creo que lo estoy complicando mucho más de lo que es....

Comment: Ser[ia bueno explicar que contiene las variables $pages y $noPages, y ponerles nombres más descriptivos a $array1 y $array2, y tratar de mostrar la estructura del array en código en vez de pegar capturas de pantallas.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que recorres `$array` para revisar si cada página se debe eliminar o no, pero en cada iteración se agrega a `$eliminar` o `$array2`.

Con tu código original necesitarías crear una variable y tomar la acción dependiendo de su valor:

```
// Crear variable para saber si se debe eliminar
$eliminar = false;
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); i++) {
    if(strtolower($page->title()) === strtolower($array[$i])) {
        // Solo se actualiza la variable para evitar duplicados
        $eliminar = true;
        // No es necesario seguir recorriendo
        break;
    }
}
// Después del ciclo se analiza la variable
if($eliminar) {
    $eliminar[] = [$page->url(), $page->title()];
} else {
    $array2[] = [$page->url(), $page->title()];
}
```

**Optimizando:**

Con la función [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) sabes inmediatamente lo que debes hacer:

```
// Todo en minúsculas, desde el inicio
$array = explode(',', strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $noPages)));
$array2 = [];
$eliminar = [];
  
foreach ($pages as $site) :
    foreach ($site->pages() as $key => $page) :
        // Busca el título con in_array()
        if(in_array(strtolower($page->title()), $array)) {
            $eliminar[] = [$page->url(), $page->title()];
        } else {
            $array2[] = [$page->url(), $page->title()];
        }
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

**[Del manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php):**

> Nota: Si se utiliza array_push() para añadir un solo elemento al array, es mejor utilizar $array[] = ya que de esta forma no existe la sobrecarga de llamar a una función.